# Robot framework upload file using choose file is not uploading the file

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

I am trying to upload file using `choose file` robot framework keyword. When I execute the test it runs successfully but the file is not uploaded.

Here is my HTML

[image]

I would like to click on `Upload Study` button to browse the file.
I tried following :

```
choose file  xpath=(//button[contains(.,"Upload Study")])  Study_File.csv
```

But it is not uploading the file. Is it because `input type=file` is not present in the xpath I used? If so how should I create the xpath?

Comment: Did you try to use locator for `input` that is few lines below your button?

Comment: Yes I tried. But its not upload the file.

Comment: After your manually select file for which html element attributes are changed?

Comment: What was the error when you tried `Choose File` on the `<input>` tag? Selenium is able to upload files only through it (it sets the filename to its property).

Comment: JaPayR - don't see change in any html element attibute

Comment: Todot - there is no error at the but fie is not uploaded

Answer (score 0):

The `choose file` keyword requires that you give the locator to an input element, not a button. From the keyword documentation:

> Inputs the file_path into file input field locator.

You probably want a locator like `id:fileUploader`

Comment: Yes I tried replacing the locator to `id:fileUploader` . No error displayed but file wasn't uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already tried using the `<input>` element as the locator, then my next guess would be that it can't find the file you're trying to upload. You have referenced the file as simply 'Study_File.csv', which suggests it's in the same directory as the test file. If it's located elsewhere then you need to provide a path to it relative to the location of your test file.

Comment: I placed the file in the same directory as the test file. At last I gave up and created `AutoIt` script to upload the file. I click on Upload button then Run `autoIt` to enter file name.